# How can I generate a new List which is filtered and sorted in a Single Line command using List Comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, sorting, filter, list-comprehension

```
a=[5,11,10,65,100,1,15,19,20,25,32,35,41]
```

I want to get multiples of 5 sorted using List Comprehension. I know how to apply List comprehension but not know how to apply filter and sort.
List Comprehension:-

```
b=[a for i in a]
```

Comment: Filter: `[i for i in a if <condition>]`. Sort: not possible with list comprehension, but you can call `sorted` with the result.

Comment: `b = sorted(x for x in a if x % 5 == 0)`

Comment: @norok2 Should be `x for x in a` not `a for x in a`, OP got it wrong too.

Comment: @norok2 that just gives a list of lists, which I don't think is what OP wants

Comment: @Thomas whoopsie :-)

Comment: @norok2 and `sorted` is not sorting a list using list comprehension.

Comment: @matszwecja sure, I assumed it just meant single line

Answer (score 1):

[List comprehensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) can be used in [Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (language reference [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#list-displays)) to implement mapping or filtering:

- [mapping](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) `[<expr> for <it> in <iterable>]`
- [filtering](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) `[<expr> for <it> in <iterable> if <cond>]`

Note that `<expr>` can be a [conditional expression (or ternary operator)](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) : `<expr1> if <cond> else <expr2>`.

There is no support for sorting upon generation, but for sorting you can use one of the following:

- [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) which creates a new sorted `list` from its iterable input
- [`list.sort()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort) method which sorts the `list` in-place.

Notice that for `sorted()` you may wish to avoid the list comprehension (to avoid using extra temporary space at the cost of a slight reduction in speed) and just use its [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions): `sorted(<expr> for <it> in <iterable> if <cond>)` (without the square brackets).

For more information on sorting in Python, see the official [Sorting HOW TO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#sortinghowto).

---

With the variables from your question this would be:

```py
# : with `list.sort()`
b_sort = [x for x in a if x % 5 == 0]
print(b_sort)
# [5, 10, 65, 100, 15, 20, 25, 35]
b_sort.sort()
print(b_sort)
# [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 65, 100]

# : with `sorted()`
b_sorted = sorted(x for x in a if x % 5 == 0)  # with generator expr
print(b_sorted)
# [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 35, 65, 100]
```

Note that you cannot use `list.sort()` with a one-liner because it acts in-place and returns `None`:

```py
# `b_sort` contains `None` and the list is lost
b_sort = [x for x in a if x % 5 == 0].sort()
print(b_sort)
# None
```